# Не могу поставить русскую локализацию в datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

Все работает здесь naveki.pro/test/index.html

Вот html код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>OCTYPE</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
     </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <script src="./data.js"></script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

И сам data.js

```
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

Я попробовал решить проблему добавлением {locale:ru} внутри datetimepicker ()

Тишина

Попробовал так:
<1script src="bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js" charset="UTF-8"><1/script1> (1 потому что не показывается, а выделить как код не могу) в index.html и в data.js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
language: 'ru'
});

И снова тишина. В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Язык (locale) нужно получить из `moment.js`, а для того чтобы это сработало нужно включить еще один скрипт ([самой локали](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/moment?path=locale)):

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/locale/ru.js"></script>`

и уже после этого вызвать:

```
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    locale: moment.locale('ru')
  });
```

```js
moment.locale('ru')
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   locale: moment.locale('ru')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>OCTYPE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/locale/ru.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="./data.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо брат, спас жизнь человеку. Добра тебе!

Comment: Держись, брат ;)